# why doesn't prestashop layered navigation block show on the front end?

Tags: module, prestashop, layered-navigation

I read docs, activated the layered navigation block, rebuilt the indexes, created a template, but it doesn't show at all on the front end. Why?

Thank you

Comment: layered navigation block is only displayed on a few pages like category page, search pages. Please check at those pages. Also clear out your prestashop and browser catch.

Comment: layer navigation used not index page that is non home page. and after fetch data it load product information to #product-list div

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the category currently active in the module's configuration.
Steps:
1. go to layered navigation block configuration
2. edit template
3. check the categories in "Categories used for this template"

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the Layered Navigation Block you need to have mod_rewrite enabled and active on your server. You also need to go to Preferences>SEOnURLs>Turn on Friendly URL.

You should also turn on Error reporting to check what, if any, errors you have. Below are instructions.

**for releases below PrestaShop 1.5.3**

config/config.inc.php

find this line
@ini_set('display_errors', 'off');

change to look like this:
@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

**PrestaShop 1.5.3+**

config/defines.inc.php

find this line
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);

change to look like this:
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);

Comment: yes seo url need to enable but it will not show home page as it work only product list page

Comment: +1 to arifur rahman

Still it's not really true: It's a simple hook matter. If you modify the module hooks to point it to some hook (maybe custom hook) that IS in home page, then it will show in home page.

Comment: In my case, I need to grant my database user "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE". I found out after activated _PS_MODE_DEV_ to true. Thanks.