# Display the Layered Navigation Block in pages like prices-drop, new-products, best-sales

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I'm trying to make the Layered Navigation Block show up in non-category pages like new-products, prices-drop, best-sales.

1. Is this an issue that could be resolved through a hook put in these pages?
   And if so, I've tried putting one of the hooks used in `/modules/blocklayered/blocklayered.php -> install() method`
   and I can't find where to put for example productListAssign Hook.
2. It's a more complex issue?

   - altering the `public function getProducts` to gather data in some other way, because the pages I want it to show in are not categories.
   - create a new method in the blocklayered class?... That would be called only in these certain pages.
3. Some other solution I didn't think of.

There's a similar question put here: [why doesn't prestashop layered navigation block show on the front end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565663/why-doesnt-prestashop-layered-navigation-block-show-on-the-front-end) ;
but there's no clear solution.

It seems that nobody active in the prestashop forum can answer this question, and I've even contacted more experienced prestashop developers, not being answered for a few days.

Please ask me for any details needed if I've skipped any.
Thanks!